# MVVMLight's EventToCommand in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin.Forms project portable - 4 sub-projects: PCL along with iOS, WP and Droid.

I would like to use `Interaction.Triggers` (from  System.Windows.Interactivity - from Blend SDK to be exact) and  EventToCommand (from MVVM Light) in my PCL project (shared UI for every platform). Is it possible?

I know that MVVM Light is portable, but `System.Windows.Interactivity` is not, so I have huge problem. **How can I use EventToCommand in Xamarin.Forms?**

Comment: did you solve this problema? I am on the same search,....using xamarin forms with .NET standard 2, I 'm trying to uimplement the ItemTp event in my mvvm, I am using mvvmligh, but I can not find any help about

Answer (score 0):

In your Xamarin project :

Right click "References", "Add References". In Assemblies -> Extensions there is System.Windows.Interactivity which can be checked and added.

This is all it takes :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it in such way:

First I added namespace to my page

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Behaviors;assembly=Xamarin.Behaviors">
```

Then I added behavior to my ContentPage

```
<b:Interaction.Behaviors>
  <b:BehaviorCollection>
    <b:EventToCommand EventName="Appearing" Command="{Binding InitializeViewModelCommand}" />
  </b:BehaviorCollection>
</b:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Hope it will help!